# Material Side Nav Generator

Tags: angular-cli, angular6

I read about the new `ng generate @angular/material:material-nav` feature in this recent Angular blog [entry](https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4) .

Unfortunately, when running the following CLI commands in a brand new project, I get an error message (see below).

```
ng add @angular/material
ng generate @angular/material:material-nav
```

Error message:

```
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"dryRun":false,"inlineStyle":false,"inlineTemplate":false,"changeDetection":"Default","styleext":"css","spec":true,"flat":false,"skipImport":false,"export":false}
Errors:

Data path "" should have required property 'name'.
```

This kind of sucks. I tried adding a name like this

```
ng generate @angular/material:material-nav home
```

But it still produces the same error. Please advice.

Angular CLI: 6.0.0
Node: 8.11.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 6.0.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error means that the property name is required, so the command should be something like this:

```
ng generate @angular/material:material-nav --name <component-name>
```

For example:

```
ng generate @angular/material:material-nav --name home
```